# C - Sub String (From POS to POS)

Tags: c, function, positioning, substring

I have a character array of length 32 and would like to take certain charcters out of it.
for example

`111111000000000000000000111111`             <32 chars

I would like to take chars 0-6 which would be `111111`

Or even take chars 26-31 which would be `111111`

```
char check_type[32];
```

Above is how I'm declaring.

What I would like to be able to do is define a function or use a function that takes that starting place, and end character.

Ive looked at many ways like using `strncpy` and `strcpy` but found no way yet.

Comment: And this function would return what? The string, I gather?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `memcpy`.

```
// Stores s[from..to) in sub.
// The caller is responsible for memory allocation.
void extract_substr(char const *s, char *sub, size_t from, size_t to)
{
    size_t sublen = to - from;
    memcpy(sub, s + from, sublen);
    sub[sublen] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: @fge: I've documented the fact that it copies `s[from..to)`, not `s[from..to]`. This fits the OP's requirements.

Comment: Well, for 0..6, yes, for 26..31, no.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply wrap `strncpy`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Creates a sub-string of range [start, end], return value must be freed */
char *substr(char *src, size_t start, size_t end)
{
   size_t sub_len = end - start + 1;
   char * new_str = malloc(sub_len + 1); /* TODO: check malloc's return value */

   strncpy(new_str, src, sub_len);
   new_str[sub_len] = '\0'; /* new_str is of size sub_len + 1 */

   return new_str;
}

int main(void)
{
   char str[] = "111111000000000000000000111111";
   char *sub_str = substr(str, 0, 5);

   puts(sub_str);

   free(sub_str);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
111111
```

Comment: I would *not* wrap `strncpy` when `memcpy` suffices. The latter is much easier to reason about.

Comment: @larsmans: Either way, it doesn't really matter too much - the OP can simply replace `strncpy` with `memcpy`, the arguments are the same. I used `strncpy` so that `substr` has the same functionality as `strncpy`, such as if a `'\0'` is encountered it'll stop copying. That *could* potentially come in handy (then again the buffer would be unnecessarily larger than it needs to be), but I really don't see it mattering too much. As I said, the OP could replace `strncpy` with `memcpy` for (slightly) better performance if he really wanted to, the function will still work by simply changing that.

Answer (score 0):

Sample:

```
char *substr(char *source, int startpos, int endpos)
{
    int len = endpos - startpos + 2; // must account for final 0
    int i = 0;

    char *src, *dst;
    char *ret = calloc(len, sizeof(char));

    if (!ret)
        return ret;

    src = source + startpos;
    dst = ret;

    while (i++ < len)
        *dst++ = *src++;

    *dst = 0;
    return ret;
}
```

Of course, free the return code when you don't need it anymore. And you notice this function will not check for the validity of `endpos` vs `startpos`.

Comment: Why `calloc`, if you're writing over every char?

Comment: This might work, but it's pretty contrived. `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1 and the copy loop should be a simple `memcpy`.

Comment: It checks for failure to allocate: `if (!ret)` is an obscure way of writing `if (ret == 0)`, though it is a way quite frequently used in actual C code, so you need to be able to read the idiom, even if you never write code using the idiom.  (In case you can't tell, I don't write code using that notation - at least, not in contexts like this.  Where the variable is a boolean, then the `if (!has_required_characteristic(something))` makes sense.)

Comment: @JackKelly I don't understand your question?

Comment: @larsmans just a habit ;) I know it could have been written `malloc(len)` but this makes things non ambiguous.

Comment: @user983969 it checks whether allocation fails, ie `calloc()` returns `NULL`

Comment: @fge: `calloc` seems like an odd choice, because as @larsmans says `sizeof(char)` is 1. Further, `calloc` zeroes the memory, but you write over every byte of it anyway. (`malloc` does not.)

Answer (score 0):

First define the required interface...perhaps:

```
int substring(char *target, size_t tgtlen, const char *source, size_t src_bgn, size_t src_end);
```

This takes a destination (target) array where the data will be copied, and is given its length.  The data will come from the source array, between positions `src_bgn` and `src_end`.  The return value will be -1 for an error, and the length of the output (excluding the terminating null).  If the target string is too short, you will get an error.

With that set of details in place, you can implement the body fairly easily, and `strncpy()` might well be appropriate this time (it often isn't).

Usage (based on your question):

```
char check_type[32] = "111111000000000000000000111111";
char result1[10];
char result2[10];

if (substring(result1, sizeof(result1), check_type, 0, 6) <= 0 ||
    substring(result2, sizeof(result2), check_type, 26, 31) <= 0)
    ...something went wrong...
else
    ...use result1 and result2...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
char* Substring(char *string, int len, int start, int end) {
  /*
  Creates a substring from a given string.
  Args:
    string: The string whose substring you need to find.
    len: The length of the string.
    start: The start position for the substring.
    end: The end position of the substring (inclusive).
  Returns:
    substring: (of type char*) which is allocated on the heap.
    NULL: on error.
  */

  // Check that the start and end position are valid.
  // If not valid, then return NULL.
  if (start < 0 || start >= len || end < 0 || end >= len) {
    return NULL;
  }

  // Allocate memory to return the substring on the heap.

  char *substring = malloc(sizeof(char) * (end - start + 2));
  int index = 0, i;

  for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    substring[index] = string[i];
    index++;
  }

  // End with a null character.
  substring[index] = '\0';
  return substring;
}

int main() {
  char str[] = "11111100000000000000000000111111";
  printf("%s\n", Substring(str, strlen(str), 0, 5));
  printf("%s\n", Substring(str, strlen(str), 26, 31));
}
```